# Jenkins slave running Maven gives log4j warning

Tags: maven, jenkins, log4j

I'm using Jenkins, and I have a Windows machine set up as a slave worker.  I have a Maven-based project that runs on the slave.  The build works correctly, but I get a warning from log4j about it not being initialized.  I'd like to scratch that itch and remove the warning, but I don't know how.

I'm not very familiar with log4j.  I do understand I could set a system property to tell it where to find a config file, but I don't know where in the Jenkins pipeline that property should be set or how.  It looks like the warning comes before Maven starts but after the slave begins the job.

Here's the snippit of console output:

```
Parsing POMs
[MyTest] $ java -cp C:\jenkins\maven3-agent.jar;C:\jenkins\tools\Maven\Maven\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.agent.Maven3Main C:\jenkins\tools\Maven\Maven C:\Users\waisbrot\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\6.0\28\5c50da9c-2d1a9aef C:\jenkins\maven3-interceptor.jar 49210
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\jenkins\workspace\MyTest\pom.xml test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not particularly proud of this, but I wasn't interested in any of that idle chatter, so I suppressed it by doing

```
jar uf <path to maven3-agent-1.2.jar>/maven3-agent-1.2.jar log4j.xml
```

where `log4j.xml` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">
  <root>
    <level value="off"/>
  </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

*NB:* the `jar` command must be executed as shown, with `log4j.xml` in the current directory.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!  Since your answer fixed the problem, I believe this is a Jenkins bug.  I've submitted a bug report on it: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17640

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a log4j.properties or a log4j.xml with valid contents in the classpath. See the log4j documentation for details

Comment: As with setting a system property, I don't know how to add an item to the classpath in that part of the Jenkins pipeline.  Do you know how I can change the classpath that Jenkins uses to launch `Maven3Main`?

Comment: It seems to me, that your application/test tries to use log4j. So you have to add the configuration to your application, i.e. putting it in a resource folder.

Comment: No, you can see that in the console output that I posted.  First Jenkins runs `Maven3Main`, then it produces the warning, then *after that* it executes Maven on my POM file.  I don't use log4j in my project.

Comment: can you give a simple example of what the log4j.properties file would contain?